# Camel 2.18 stream caching: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: apache-camel

I am using Camel 2.18 and Java 8. Below is some code with routing. I POST such JSON to this service:

```
{
    "bigField": "testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest",
    "smallField": "234"
}
```

And the problem is that the bigField is quite big, can be 256MB. Thats why I am thinking of stream caching in Camel: http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html Not sure if I can apply it in my scenario ? What I understand is that this mechanism should store the stream on a disk little by little ? I created /tmp/cachedir and I see how Camel is creating and deleting some temporary files.

```
6:15:23.505 [qtp422330142-21 - /myservice/v1/oper] DEBUG org.apache.camel.util.FileUtil - Retrying attempt 0 to delete file: /tmp/cachedir/cos7138988885969104934.tmp
16:15:23.505 [qtp422330142-21 - /myservice/v1/oper] DEBUG org.apache.camel.util.FileUtil - Tried 1 to delete file: /tmp/cachedir/cos7138988885969104934.tmp with result: true
16:15:23.505 [qtp422330142-21 - /myservice/v1/oper] DEBUG org.apache.camel.util.FileUtil - Retrying attempt 0 to delete file: /tmp/cachedir/cos8802932624903146810.tmp
16:15:23.505 [qtp422330142-21 - /myservice/v1/oper] DEBUG org.apache.camel.util.FileUtil - Tried 1 to delete file: /tmp/cachedir/cos8802932624903146810.tmp with result: true
16:15:23.505 [qtp422330142-21 - /myservice/v1/oper] DEBUG org.apache.camel.util.FileUtil - Retrying attempt 0 to delete file: /tmp/cachedir/cos91165405800652292.tmp
16:15:23.505 [qtp422330142-21 - /myservice/v1/oper] DEBUG org.apache.camel.util.FileUtil - Tried 1 to delete file: /tmp/cachedir/cos91165405800652292.tmp with result: true
16:15:23.506 [qtp422330142-21 - /myservice/v1/oper] DEBUG org.apache.camel.util.FileUtil - Retrying attempt 0 to delete file: /tmp/cachedir/cos6540772182497948066.tmp
16:15:23.506 [qtp422330142-21 - /myservice/v1/oper] DEBUG org.apache.camel.util.FileUtil - Tried 1 to delete file: /tmp/cachedir/cos6540772182497948066.tmp with result: true
16:15:23.506 [qtp422330142-21 - /myservice/v1/oper] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - RESPONSE /myservice/v1/oper  201
```

So it seems to be working. But I am using this mechanism to protect myself from OutOfMemory exceptions. So I wrote Junit sending bigField created like this:

```
headers.setAll(map);
        char[] chars = new char[20000000];
        Arrays.fill(chars, 'a');
        String bigField = new String(chars);
```

I started my Spring Boot app with  `JAVA_OPTS="-Xms60m -Xmx128m"`

What I am missing ? I thought that this stream caching mechanism would protect me from clients sending bodies event bigger than Xmx - 128MB but it fails at 20MB.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends RouteBuilder {

@Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        setupStreamCaching();

        restConfiguration().host("0.0.0.0").port(PORT)
                .endpointProperty("headerFilterStrategy", "#myHeaderFilterStrategy")
                .endpointProperty("matchOnUriPrefix", "true")
                .endpointProperty("sendServerVersion", "false")
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json);

        rest(API_CONTEXT + V1)
                .post(API_OPERATION)
                .type(RequestModel.class)
                .outType(Response.class)
                .consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .to(MAIN_ROUTE);

        from(MAIN_ROUTE)
                .routeId(MAIN_ROUTE)
                .process(requestValidator)
                .to(SERVICE_CALL)
                .end();


    private void setupStreamCaching() {
            getContext().getStreamCachingStrategy().setSpoolDirectory("/tmp/cachedir");
    getContext().getStreamCachingStrategy().setSpoolThreshold(64 * 1024);
    getContext().getStreamCachingStrategy().setBufferSize(16 * 1024);
        }
```

http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html

> 3:30:24.584 [qtp1492219097-24 - /myservice/v1/oper] DEBUG
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint - filled 3432
>   SelectChannelEndPoint@44b2fa12{/10.0.2.2:57125<->1080,Open,in,out,-,-,0/30000,HttpConnection}{io=0,kio=0,kro=1}
>   13:30:24.585 [qtp1492219097-24 - /myservice/v1/oper] DEBUG
>   o.e.jetty.server.HttpConnection -
>   HttpConnection@13dbbbcc[REFILLING,SelectChannelEndPoint@44b2fa12{/10.0.2.2:57125<->1080,Open,in,out,-,-,0/30000,HttpConnection}{io=0,kio=0,kro=1}][p=HttpParser{s=CONTENT,19996672
>   of
>   20000104},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},c=HttpChannelOverHttp@4b6953ae{r=1,c=false,a=DISPATCHED,uri=/myservice/v1/oper}]
>   filled 3432 13:30:24.585 [qtp1492219097-24 - /myservice/v1/oper] DEBUG
>   org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - parseNext s=CONTENT
>   HeapByteBuffer@42f6e192[p=0,l=3432,c=8192,r=3432]={<<>>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}
>   13:30:24.585 [qtp1492219097-24 - /myservice/v1/oper] DEBUG
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel -
>   HttpChannelOverHttp@4b6953ae{r=1,c=false,a=DISPATCHED,uri=/myservice/v1/oper}
>   content java.nio.HeapByteBufferR[pos=0 lim=3432 cap=8192] 13:30:24.585
>   [qtp1492219097-24 - /myservice/v1/oper] DEBUG
>   org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - parseNext s=CONTENT
>   HeapByteBuffer@42f6e192[p=3432,l=3432,c=8192,r=0]={aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...-21T17:32:28Z"}<<<>>>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}
>   13:30:24.585 [qtp1492219097-24 - /myservice/v1/oper] DEBUG
>   org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - CONTENT --> END 13:30:24.585
>   [qtp1492219097-24 - /myservice/v1/oper] DEBUG
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel -
>   HttpChannelOverHttp@4b6953ae{r=1,c=false,a=DISPATCHED,uri=/myservice/v1/oper}
>   messageComplete 13:30:24.585 [qtp1492219097-24 - /myservice/v1/oper]
>   DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput - HttpInputOverHTTP@63602aee
>   EOF 13:30:24.585 [qtp1492219097-24 - /myservice/v1/oper] DEBUG
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint - filled 0
>   SelectChannelEndPoint@44b2fa12{/10.0.2.2:57125<->1080,Open,in,out,-,-,1/30000,HttpConnection}{io=0,kio=0,kro=1}
>   13:30:24.586 [qtp1492219097-24 - /myservice/v1/oper] DEBUG
>   o.e.jetty.server.HttpConnection -
>   HttpConnection@13dbbbcc[REFILLING,SelectChannelEndPoint@44b2fa12{/10.0.2.2:57125<->1080,Open,in,out,-,-,2/30000,HttpConnection}{io=0,kio=0,kro=1}][p=HttpParser{s=END,20000104
>   of
>   20000104},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},c=HttpChannelOverHttp@4b6953ae{r=1,c=false,a=DISPATCHED,uri=/myservice/v1/oper}]
>   filled 0 13:30:24.586 [qtp1492219097-24 - /myservice/v1/oper] DEBUG
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput - HttpInputOverHTTP@63602aee eof
>   EOF 13:30:24.586 [qtp1492219097-24 - /myservice/v1/oper] DEBUG
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput - HttpInputOverHTTP@63602aee eof
>   EOF 13:30:27.462 [qtp1492219097-24 - /myservice/v1/oper] WARN 
>   o.e.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - /myservice/v1/oper
>   org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException: Error during type conversion
>   from type: java.lang.String to the required type: java.lang.String
>   with value [Body is instance of org.apache.camel.StreamCache] due
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.createTypeConversionException(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:629)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.convertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getBody(MessageSupport.java:78)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getBody(MessageSupport.java:53)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.MessageHelper.extractBodyAsString(MessageHelper.java:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.rest.RestConsumerBindingProcessor.process(RestConsumerBindingProcessor.java:162)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
>     at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)   at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.jetty.CamelContinuationServlet.doService(CamelContinuationServlet.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.service(CamelServlet.java:74)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
>   Java heap space   at
>   org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1763)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.invokeMethod(ObjectHelper.java:1358)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.converter.StaticMethodTypeConverter.convertTo(StaticMethodTypeConverter.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.doConvertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:306)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.convertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:133)
>     ... 27 common frames omitted
>
> Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space    at
>   java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)     at
>   java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
>     at
>   java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:596)
>     at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:190)   at
>   org.apache.camel.converter.IOConverter.toString(IOConverter.java:318)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.converter.IOConverter.toString(IOConverter.java:307)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.converter.IOConverter.toString(IOConverter.java:364)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.invokeMethod(ObjectHelper.java:1354)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.converter.StaticMethodTypeConverter.convertTo(StaticMethodTypeConverter.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.doConvertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:306)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.convertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:133)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getBody(MessageSupport.java:78)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getBody(MessageSupport.java:53)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.MessageHelper.extractBodyAsString(MessageHelper.java:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.rest.RestConsumerBindingProcessor.process(RestConsumerBindingProcessor.java:162)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
>     at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)   at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.jetty.CamelContinuationServlet.doService(CamelContinuationServlet.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.service(CamelServlet.java:74)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)

Comment: You are using json binding mode, which will marshal/unmarshal the stream into those Java objects, and they will then be loaded into memory. So you can turn that off by removing that one